# Deploying laravel 5 on Windows server with WAMP server

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, laravel-5

Can I ask for some help? I'm deploying my Laravel project to a windows server. I installed WAMP server and use MySQL for my database. I use my public IP, because we have no domain name yet, so we just use a public IP and then port forwarding it to my server's IP. My problem is, how can I see my site, if this is my public IP xxx.xx.xxx.xx? Do I need to use the PHP artisan serve? But is there a way not to use the PHP artisan serve ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the WAMP server, you can use the localhost or 127.0.0.1 and the path_to_your_project

ex : 127.0.0.1/myproject/**public/**

And you will see your project !